# How to authenicate using static role in Loopback ACL

Tags: loopbackjs

Having issues getting authentication working using static roles access control within models. Things seem to be working when using ACL's with principal types $authenticated and $everyone. So access controls are in place and functioning as expected when logged in and logged out. As ACL's are moved over to static roles authentication fails and a 401 is returned. Loopback built in models for for roles, role-mapping, and user are being used. I've tried using ROLE and USER as principalTypes.
Creating User, Role, and principal with RoleMapping:

```
User.create({
    username: 'admin',
    email: 'admin@admin.com',
    password: 'password',
    active: true
}, 
function (err, user) {
    Role.create({
        name: 'Admin'
    }, 
    function (err, role) {
        if (err) throw err;

        console.log('Created role:', role);

        //make user an admin
        role.principals.create({
            principalType: RoleMapping.USER,
            //principalType: RoleMapping.ROLE,
            principalId: user.id,
            active: true
        }, 
        function (err, principal) {
            if (err) throw err;

            console.log('Principal:', principal);
        });
    });
});
```

Customer Model:

```
"name": "Customer",
"base": "PersistedModel",
"strict": false,
"idInjection": false,
"options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
},
"properties": {
    "name": {
        "type": "string",
        "required": true
    },
    "description": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "active": {
        "type": "boolean"
    }
},
"validations": [],
"relations": {
    "products": {
        .........
    },
    "users": {
        .........
    }
},
"acls": [
    {
        "accessType": "*",
        "principalType": "ROLE",
        "principalId": "$everyone",
        "permission": "DENY"
    },
    {
        WORKS AS EXPECTED
        "accessType": "*",
        "principalType": "ROLE",
        "principalId": "$authenticated",
        "permission": "ALLOW"
    },
    {
        RETURNS 401 AFTER LOGGING IN AS USER ASSIGNED TO ROLE
        "accessType": "*",
        "principalType": "ROLE",
        "principalId": "Admin",
        "permission": "ALLOW"
    }
],
"methods": []
```

User record created:

```
"_id" : ObjectId("55b7c34d6033a33758038c3b"),
"username" : "admin",
"password" : ....,
"email" : "admin@admin.com",
"active" : true
```

Role record:

```
"_id" : ObjectId("55b7c34d6033a33758038c3e"),
"name" : "Admin",
"created" : ISODate("2015-07-28T18:00:45.336Z"),
"modified" : ISODate("2015-07-28T18:00:45.336Z")
```

RoleMapping Record:

```
"_id" : ObjectId("55b7c34d6033a33758038c41"),
"principalType" : "USER",
"principalId" : "55b7c34d6033a33758038c3b",
"roleId" : ObjectId("55b7c34d6033a33758038c3e"),
"active" : true
```

Thanks before hand for any help!

Comment: Issue was that the static role was not registered as a [role handler](http://apidocs.strongloop.com/loopback/#role-registerresolver)

Comment: Hi, I am having same problem. How did you solve this. can you please elaborate. Thanks

Comment: Think the issue was resolved by following the steps listed under the "Dynamic roles" portion of : https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Defining+and+using+roles

Answer (score 0):

When you define the user in principalId, try try instead:

```
principalId: user[0].id,
```

Answer (score 0):

Please note at:

RoleMapping.principalType: USER (mean user, not ROLE)

RoleMapping.principalId: USER_ID (because define RoleMapping.principalType is USER)

acls: [
{ "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "admin",
}
]

I have tested, it's working

```
Role
—————————
_id: ObjectId(5c70409a98103f1af6ee2b55)
name: “admin”,
description: “Only Admin can write”,


Role Mapping
——————————
_id: ObjectId(5c7040f998103f1af6ee2b57)
principalType: USER
principalId: 5c72b9ef79dcf14443c1aa3b
roleId: ObjectId(5c70409a98103f1af6ee2b55)


User
——————————
_id: ObjectId(5c72b9ef79dcf14443c1aa3b)
firstName: “”,
lastName: “”,
email:””,
Active:””,
emailVerified:

ACL
 {
      "accessType": "WRITE",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "admin",
      "permission": "ALLOW"
 }
```